# In IntelliJ IDEA, how can I set an audio notification when a breakpoint is reached?

Tags: intellij-idea, breakpoints, conditional-breakpoint

With IntelliJ IDEA, when setting a breakpoint that isn't hit frequently (or not at all), I leave my computer. I'll return every 10 minutes or so to check if the breakpoint has been reached. It would be more efficient if I could hear when the breakpoint is reached. Is this possible?

1. The following code works, but I need to execute an `.mp4` file instead of `.app`.  See the second block of code for that attempt, which doesn't work.
2. Though the code works for `.app`, how would I set the breakpoint to execute that code when it is reached?

**This works:**

```java
try {
   Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/open -a iTunes.app");
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**This doesn't:**

```java
try {
   Runtime.getRuntime().exec("MacintoshHD/Users/myusername/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Tones -a 01 Zelda Gets Item Alert Tone.m4a");
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

By the way, I did try putting quotes around the path items that had spaces. That didn't work either.

Answer (score 4):

Add this to `Evaluate and log`:

```java
Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("some.wav"));
clip.open(inputStream);
clip.start();
Thread.sleep(10000);
```

or execute some application to do it:

```java
try {
   Runtime.getRuntime().exec("\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Winamp\\winamp.exe\" \"C:\\some.mp4\"");
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Nice. I took this to the extreme and fixed the import bug with the newer Intellij. https://gist.github.com/philard/b92214e230e3c1de5f6d65b952b3de14

Answer (score 1):

[Since 2020.3](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-242373/Implement-notification-for-breakpoint-hit-action#focus=Comments-27-4390985.0-0), you can go to `Settings | Appearance & Behavior | Notifications`, choose the **Breakpoint hit** item and then check "Play sound".

[image]
<sup>*(image taken from the linked issue)*</sup>

Unfortunately, it's not possible to configure which sound to play. A feature request is [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-251971/Play-different-user-selectable-sounds-on-hitting-specific-breakpoint).

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows, you can create a very simple script in PowerShell, which will make a beeping sound whenever it is ran. (This will run at frequency 500 for 3 seconds).

```
[console]::beep(500,3000)
```

Then in the evaluate section of the debugger, just add a watch variable that calls the script using PowerShell:

```java
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("powershell.exe \"C:\\Users\\myusername\\test.ps1\"")
```